# Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: rest, jersey

It was working good before but now my restful service showing this error. I am running with tomcat 8.0.

> SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/D:/Myprogram/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/RestFulApi/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar] for annotations
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:55)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50568085) helped me fix something very similar...

Check if it helps to (temporarily) remove `file:/D:/Myprogram/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/RestFulApi/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar` (maybe it was compiled for the "wrong" Java?).