# getting Invalid byte tag in constant pool : 19

Tags: java, rest, web-scraping, jersey, tomcat8

i am creating one webservice and getting error like

> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19.

i am using tomcat 8.0 and java versoin is 1.8.0.152.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7 - Servlet 3.0: Invalid byte tag in constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751920/tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A constant pool entry with tag type 19 is a module descriptor; see [JVM spec table 4.4-A](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4).  I think you have attempted to use BCEL on a class compiled with a Java 9 (or later) compiler:

- The BCEL version you are using doesn't understand the tag.
- The class wouldn't load in a Java 8 JVM anyway.   Modules were only introduced in Java 9, and the class file's major version number should be too recent for a Java 8 JVM.

Comment: I love when answers explain things and not only give a solution! Thx!