# Spring Tomcat error Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I added a few Jars to my project and the error popped up. I'm wondering if upgrading the version of my tomcat might work but I'm not sure what is my current tomcat version or know how to upgrade. Any help is appreciated!

JDK 14
Tomcat 7 ( suspected )

Pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Alex</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoronavirusWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable> 
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error. This error pops up multiple times in the console

```html
PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/jinyi/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/3.141.5/selenium-safari-driver-3.141.5.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
```

Comment: Try to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567687/getting-invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool-19) and try to modify your `<source>1.8</source> <target>1.8</target>` at last to java 9

Comment: Run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see tomcat version embedded in spring boot. If you want to use any specific version, Just override the properties set in spring's parent pom as per your case : `<properties<tomcat.version>9.0.5</tomcat.version><properties>`

Comment: The program is spring mvc and tomcatt is implemented through the plug-in, trying to add it as a normal dependency wouldn't work for some reason.